# Udacity Image processing

Tags: tensorflow, style-transfer

I was trying to follow the instructions for the following TensorFlow demo, where style of an art is transfered to another image:

[image: Demo of the image processing]

I successfully installed TensorFlow and the other things. But when i tried to run

```
'python evaluate.py --checkpoint ./rain-princess.ckpt --in-path <path_to_input_file> --out-path ./output_image.jpg',
```

my access was denied.

[image: Image of the output]

Can anyone shed light as to why this occurs? I am still quite new to this.

Comment: Haven't seen the tutorial before, but are you sure you have the correct commands? make sure there is a space between `--checkpoint ./rain-princess.ckpt` and `--in_path C:\...`. (also no need to insert the path between `<..>`).

Comment: Please include the screenshot content as actual text (code snipped).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try this

```
python evaluate.py --checkpoint ./rain-princess.ckpt --in-path ./joker.jpg --out-path ./output_image.jpg
```

Comment: Could you explain why and how this could fix the `access denied` error ?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the image which you are passing as input is in fast-style-transfer folder.

 `python evaluate.py --checkpoint ./rain-princess.ckpt --in-path <path_to_input_file> --out-path ./output_image.jpg`

 As for the above code in place of `path_to_input_file` just insert your image name

 For example if the image name is saved as jac (jpg format) in fast-style-transfer folder, then code would look like

 `python evaluate.py --checkpoint ./rain-princess.ckpt --in-path jac.jpg --out-path ./output_image.jpg`

Answer (score 0):

It should be `rain_princess.ckpt` and let the image be `image.jpg` in the folder then code is:-

```
python evaluate.py --checkpoint ./rain_princess.ckpt --in-path image.jpg --out-path ./output_image.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone is still having the same problem, it only worked with me when I used Python 3.7 :

```
conda create -n style-transfer python=3.7
```